# How can I get the first instance of an event per day with multiple columns including a datetime and return those columns plus the full datetime value?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, query-optimization, distinct

I need to generate a SQL script that will pull out Distinct entries using a number of columns, one of which is a datetime column.  I am only interested in the first occurrence of the day per event and the query needs to span multiple days.  The query will be run against a very large database and can potentially be returning hundreds of thousands of results if not millions.  Therefore I need this script to be as efficient as possible as well.  This will eventually be a script running in SSRS to pull access transactions.

I've tried using GROUP BY, DISTINCT, subqueries, FIRST, and such without success.  All the examples I can find online don't have JOIN statements or calculated columns such as only gathering the date from a datetime field.

I've simplified the below script some to only pull one day and one door, but the prod will be multiple days and doors.  This code returns the data I need, I don't care about the COUNT, but I also need to get the `(DateAdd(minute,-(ServerLocaleOffset),ServerUTC))` field in my result set as well somehow.  The problem is since it goes down to the second it makes all records DISTINCT.

```
DECLARE @Begin datetime2 = '4/10/2019',
        @End datetime2 = '4/11/2019',
        @Door varchar(max) = 'Front Entrance'

SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (DateAdd(minute,-(ServerLocaleOffset),ServerUTC)),101) AS 'Date'
        ,AJ.PrimaryObjectIdentity
        ,AJ.SecondaryObjectIdentity
        ,AJ.MessageType
        ,AJ.PrimaryObjectName
        ,AJ.SecondaryObjectName
        ,AP.Text13
        ,COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM Access.JournalLogView AJ
LEFT OUTER JOIN Access.Personnel as AP on AP.GUID = AJ.PrimaryObjectIdentity
WHERE (MessageType like 'CardAdmitted' OR MessageType like 'CardRejected')
AND (DateAdd(minute,-(ServerLocaleOffset),ServerUTC)) BETWEEN @Begin AND @End
AND (SecondaryObjectName IN (@Door))

GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (DateAdd(minute,-(ServerLocaleOffset),ServerUTC)),101)
        ,PrimaryObjectIdentity
        ,SecondaryObjectIdentity
        ,MessageType
        ,PrimaryObjectName
        ,SecondaryObjectName
        ,Text13
ORDER BY AJ.PrimaryObjectName
```

I want to get the columns called out in the SELECT statement plus the datetime which includes the second.  Again I also want the most efficient way of pulling this data as well.  Thank you very much.

Comment: can you provide us with the structure of table with the datetime column?

Comment: ServerUTC is the datetime2 column and the serverlocaloffset just records how many minutes off of GMT is the timezone of the server.

Comment: Ok...even then, my query should work....did you try that...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming PrimaryObjectIdentity is the primary key to find the personnel in JournalLogview and ServerLocaleOffset as the datetime column in that table,I have written down this:

```
DECLARE @Begin datetime2 = '4/10/2019',
        @End datetime2 = '4/11/2019',
        @Door varchar(max) = 'Front Entrance'

WITH cte 
AS(
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(PARTITION BY PrimaryObjectIdentity,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (DateAdd(minute,-(ServerLocaleOffset),ServerUTC)),101) ORDER BY ServerLocaleOffset) AS row_num,
--whatever the columns you want here
*
FROM
Access.JournalLogView)

SELECT
         DateAdd(minute,-(ServerLocaleOffset),ServerUTC)) AS 'DateTime'
        ,AJ.PrimaryObjectIdentity
        ,AJ.SecondaryObjectIdentity
        ,AJ.MessageType
        ,AJ.PrimaryObjectName
        ,AJ.SecondaryObjectName
        ,AP.Text13
        --I guess count(*) won't be of use a we are selecting only the first row
        ,COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM cte AJ
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Access.Personnel as AP 
on 
AP.GUID = AJ.PrimaryObjectIdentity
WHERE 
AJ.row_num = 1
AND (MessageType like 'CardAdmitted' OR MessageType like 'CardRejected')
AND (DateAdd(minute,-(ServerLocaleOffset),ServerUTC)) BETWEEN @Begin AND @End
AND (SecondaryObjectName IN (@Door))

GROUP BY (DateAdd(minute,-(ServerLocaleOffset),ServerUTC))
        ,PrimaryObjectIdentity
        ,SecondaryObjectIdentity
        ,MessageType
        ,PrimaryObjectName
        ,SecondaryObjectName
        ,Text13
ORDER BY AJ.PrimaryObjectName
```

In this query, I have used PARTITION to partition the whole table by each user, date and then assign row_number() to each row starting from the first entry of each user in that particular date. So, any row with row_num() = 1 will give you the first entry of that user in that date (which is the same condition I have used in the where clause). Hope this helps :)